# Browser Session causes Event Listeners to Increase

Tags: session, google-chrome-devtools, event-listener

I have a page that checks if a user is logged in, and if they aren't, it redirects them to the login page and I've been experiencing some strange behavior with the Event Listener Count in the Chrome Dev Tools.

When the user is redirected to the login page, logs in successfully, then redirected back to the home page the Event Listener Count is around 6000.

When the user closes the tab, then navigates back to the home page (this time skipping the login screen because their session is still active) the Event Listener Count is only 4000.

What could cause this dramatic difference in the number of Event Listeners? The same page is being loaded both times, the only difference is the session is already established...

What is it about already having an active session that causes the Event Listener Count to drop so much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timeline tab shows current state of the *tab* memory not the *page* memory. It means that it's not necessarily true that it contains only memory allocated by a current website. If you have visited couple of pages using same tab then garbage from previous pages may still be in the tabs memory.

That's why in the new tab you've got expected number of 4000 listeners, while in the 'old' tab, that you have used to visit `'home page'->'login page'->'home page'`, you can see 6000 listeners.

You can force garbage collection using 'trash bin' button in the bottom left corner of the devtools. After you click it you should see a drop in number of listeners.

[image: Garbage collection icon in Chrome Dev Tools]

**BTW** You've got 4000+ event listeners on a webpage? This is *a lot*. I haven't seen a page that has more than 1000 listeners (this page has 80, twitter has 200 and gmail has 1000). If you are not working on some super complicated webapp (4 times more complicated than gmail) then you are doing something wrong. If you are using jQuery make sure that you know what `$('ul').on('click','li',function(){})` does. If you are using vanilla JS, make sure you have read about event bubbling and how it can help you to reduce number of listeners.

Comment: Thank you! this is what i was hoping. And yes, I am working on a very complicated business app, the reason there are so many listeners is mainly due to our use of the our jqwidgets feature rich grids (we have a lot of them).